# Compiling template class from header file not working

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to write a template class for matrices for a university assignment (I have spoken with the professor over email and we haven't been able to resolve the issue). The class definition is a given header file "Matrix.h", the member functions are to be defined in a file "Matrix.cc" and a test file "test_matrix.cc" to implement and test the functions. The issue is getting anything to compile. Right now "Matrix.cc" contains only the class constructor, and "test_matrix.cc" only contains the initializing of one object of type matrix.

This is header file provided "Matrix.h"

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Matrix {
public:
   Matrix(int m = 0, int n = 0, T fv = 0);
   Matrix(const Matrix<T>& M);
   ~Matrix();
   Matrix(const vector<T> &v, int m, int n  );
   const T& operator()(int i, int j) const; //to work on const objects
   T& operator()(int i, int j);
   Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& m);
  Matrix<T>& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& x);
  Matrix<T>& operator-=(const Matrix<T>& x);
  Matrix<T>& operator*=(const Matrix<T>& m);
  void print(ostream& sout) const; //display the matrix onto output stream
                                    // sout neatly
  int ncols() const {return cols;}
  int nrows() const {return rows;}
private:
    int rows, cols;
    T  *data; //array to hold matrix elements
};
// nonmembers
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& l, const Matrix<T>&r);
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T>& l, const Matrix<T>&r);
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& l, const Matrix<T>&r);
#include "Matrix.cc" //to compile templates
#endif
```

This is the member function definition file "Matrix.cc"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int m, int n, T fv)
: rows(m), cols(n)
{
    data = new T[rows*cols];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        data[i] = fv;
    cout << "CC" << endl;
}
```

And this is the test file "test_matrix.cc"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Matrix one(3,3,6);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling test_matrix.cc gives an error "Use of class template requires template arguments"

Compiling Matrix.cc gives the error "Redefinition of Matrix"

I have tried commenting out the "#include "Matrix.h"" in Matrix.cc, adding "#include "Matrix.cc"" in test_matrix.cc and various other assortments to get rid of the redefinition error to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fullll definition of the template must be visible to client code. Because a template can't be compiled to binary unless instantiated with fully provided/deduced parameters. Input parameters to template can be any class and compiler cannot make assumptions on properties of the those inputs(`class T` in this example). Put all member definitions in your header file (`Matrix.h`) and get rid of `Matrix.cc`.

Another problem with your code is unguarded header file `Matrix.h`; whenever you define a header file, you must make sure it will not cause code duplication, in case of multiple inclusions in the same translation unit. Because `#include`(anything that begins with `#`) is a preprocessor directive/construct. Preprocessor is a dumb code generator that modifies your source code by replacing/adding some text to translation units just before compiling them. Whenever it encounters an `#include` directive, it injects all the text content of the specified header into current file.
There are 2 methods to create an include guard the simpler way is to add a `#pragma once` directive at the beginning of your `Matrix.h`. The harder way is to organize your header like this:

```
#ifndef MY_MATRIX_GUARD
#define MY_MATRIX_GUARD
/*put everything here*/
#endif  // ! MY_MATRIX_GUARD
```

And put all your code between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` preprocessor directives. Make sure nothing extra resides on the `#ifndef` line, or you will get a long list of darns, complains, and errors from the compiler.
Your snippet has memory leak problem too. You'd better stay off raw pointers. Declare the `data` member as `uniqe_ptr` or `vector`.
Next tip: start with simpler code; you don't seem to be ready for the level of complexity in current code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, The OP has been modified after I've seen it last. Not my fault that you haven't seen it before. Bad manors from the OP.

Comment: That's when I started writing. I didn't refresh during that period.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.

- Matrix.h includes Matrix.cc...which in turn includes Matrix.h.
- You're missing a definition of `~Matrix()`
- You declare but don't define operators +, -, / for a Matrix (but you don't use them either).

A `Matrix.cc` something like this should work a bit better:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int m, int n, T fv)
: rows(m), cols(n)
{
    data = new T[rows*cols];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        data[i] = fv;
    std::cout << "CC\n";
}
 
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() { 
   delete [] data;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Unfortunately for sake of the assignment I am not allowed to modify the header file. I did add the destructor (plan was to create and test member functions one by one with the declarations provided, should have known to create that as soon as I made the constructor however). The main issue is that when attempting to compile the error given is that the Matrix constructor is being redefined, which by the sounds of your first point may be an issue the header?

Comment: You don't need to modify the header. Mostly you need to modify `Matrix.cc` so it doesn't include the header.

Comment: @TaberDave, That's bad practice. I do not advice that. But you can just do as Jerry pointed above.

Comment: @Red.Wave: I agree it's a bad practice--but from his comment about it being an assignment, I'd guess it's homework where he has no choice in the matter.